# Linked Lists & Pointer Syntax errors

Tags: c, pointers, syntax, struct

This program simply takes a file with ASCII lines, puts it into a linked-list stack, and then prints the reversed list to a new file in the same ASCII format.

My struct Code:

```
typedef struct Node{
    char info[15];
    struct Node *ptr;
};
```

I'm getting the following errors on Main. Most have to do where I declare the new Node Head... what's wrong with that syntax?:

```
Errors
    strrev.c:28: error: ‘Node’ undeclared (first use in this function)
    strrev.c:28: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
    strrev.c:28: error: for each function it appears in.)
    strrev.c:28: error: ‘head’ undeclared (first use in this function)
    strrev.c:34: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘strcpy’ from incompatible pointer type
   /usr/include/string.h:128: note: expected ‘char * __restrict__’ but argument is of         type ‘char **’
```

Main Code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc != 3) {
        fprintf(stderr, "usage: intrev <input file> <output file>\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    FILE *fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    assert(fp != NULL);


    Node *head = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    head->ptr=NULL;

    char str[15];
    while (fgets(str, 15, fp) != NULL){
        struct Node *currNode = malloc(sizeof(Node));
        strcpy(currNode->info, str);
        currNode->ptr = head;
        head=currNode;
    }

    char *outfile = argv[2];
    FILE *outfilestr = fopen(outfile, "w");
    assert(fp != NULL);

    while (head->ptr != NULL){
        fprintf(outfilestr, "%s\n", head->info);
        head = head->ptr;
    }

    fclose(fp);
    fclose(outfilestr);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is `char *info[15]` supposed to do in your mind? Can you please try and verify your assumptions of how C works on a small program first and move to a more complex one only after you're confident how it works?

Comment: It's a character array holding a line from a file.

Comment: But it isn't. It's an array of pointers. In fact, your compiler should have given you a warning about this. Are you sure you've enabled all warnings?

Comment: Or, it will when I add it.

Once again, the problem seems to occur when I declare a new head node. Coming from Java, I guess I don't see where the problem is coming from.

Comment: gcc -o strrev strrev.c -Wall -m32 -O --> so yes

Comment: Please `man strcpy`. You are copying an array of `char` to an array of pointers of `char`.

Comment: Another comment - not an answer to the direct question: for each `malloc` you must have a `free`. In its current state, your program has a memory leak (well, it would if it compiled).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have the wrong syntax for `typedef` of a structure. You need to place the `typedef` name *after* the structure definition:

```
typedef struct Node  /* <- structure name */
{
    /* ... */
} Node;  /* <- typedef name */
```

And it's okay to use the same name for both the structure and the type, as both live in different namespaces.

Comment: wouldn't it also legal to omit the structure name?

Comment: Or use `struct Node` as in the `while` loop. But in that case there's no need for having the typedef at all.

Comment: Holy cow. I.. I'll be honest, maybe because I'm new, but I'm not entirely sure why that worked... Do you know where in K&R I can read up more on this?

Comment: @xmoex While it's legal, the OP uses a pointer to the structure inside the structure itself, so then need to give the structure a name.

Comment: @katiea I never owned a copy of any version of K&R so can't really say.

Comment: Okay: One last question for you guys (@gauthier @joachim) -- this program is doing exactly what it's supposed now, but there are extra new lines... For example:

'1, 2, 3, 4' may all be on new lines for the input file, and the output file should have 4,3,2,1 all on new lines. But my current output has extra new lines between each output... I never put a new "newline" character in, so why is this?

Comment: @katiea It's how [`fgets`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) works. It read and leaves the newline in the string, and you need to manually get rid of it (typically `str[strlen(str) - 1] = '\0';` will work, be sure that the `fgets` call didn't fail first though).

Comment: Got it. Thank you again.

Edit: I seriously should have known that since I created a second mini strcat using fgets for that exact reasoning... *sigh*

Answer (score 2):

You need to have a `Node` typedef first

```
typedef struct Node Node;
typedef struct Node{
char *info[15];
Node *ptr;
};
```

Or do it in one

```
typedef struct Node{
    char *info[15];
    struct Node *ptr;
} Node;
```

Comment: The declaration of the `struct` does not need `typedef`. It is not a type definition (the second code line should be only `struct Node{`).